# SDL Event Debug Problem

Tags: events, sdl

I am currently trying to get SDL events to work, but problem is that the program is not working.

When I ran the program; it open and closes very quickly, and the debug gave these errors:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xb60) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xe00) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x628) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[868] My Project.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

I am using Visual Studio C++ Express Edition 2008 and the includes files are:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include  <windows.h>
#include  <string>
```

The code that I'm trying to get working can be found at:
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson04/index.php

Answer (score 0):

That code is trying to load a file name "x.png". If you do not have a proper PNG file with that name in the working directory then the program will exit with an error code of 1.